# How to convert Json string with key-value pair into string with only value

Tags: java, json

I actually converted my pojo data into json string this way,

```
 Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
    String json=gson.toJson(user);
```

I got the json string but that is not the format i actually need, i got

```
json = {"userID":300,"userName":"asd","password":"s","enabled":1}
```

So, I want to convert Json string with key-value pair as below ,

```
{"userID":300,"userName":"asd","password":"s","enabled":1}
```

into Json string with only value (without key) as below

```
[300,"asd","s",1]
```

Comment: In my opinion, bad practice. You have to define which property has a value and what value have that property.

Comment: you should specify if you need an explicit ordering in your list, a dictionary mapping is unordered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could whack the properties of the `user` into a `List<Object>` and then JSON that.

This would mean GSON made an JSON array out of the `List` and you would get what you want.

As this doesn't seem to make much sense as a use case you would have to do a bit of hardcoding - I don't think GSON can do this for you:

```
final List<Object> props = new LinkedList<>();
props.add(user.getId());
props.add(user.getUserName());
//etc
final String json=gson.toJson(props);
```

Comment: I think it's not a good usage. To do that you have to build an `user` object first. If you have an array of users, you have to do a loop to add a value for each property (if you get values from a database, for example) and then another loop to extract each value... Too much server overload in my opinion. Anyway, as I said in my answer, this question is a really bad practice. You need to define each `property:value` for your objects.

Comment: @DaGLiMiOuX i agree that it is bad practice, I have said as much in my answer. Your database example - the data is _already_ in this form - there is no reason to create a `Collection<User>` from the `ResultSet` only to extract the values again.

Answer (score 1):

So I continue after your string `json`.

```
// lets deserialize your json string and get a hashmap
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Object>>(){}.getType();
HashMap<String, Object> hm = gson.fromJson(json, collectionType);
String finalJson = gson.toJson(hm.values());
// aand taa-daa!!
System.out.println(finalJson);
```

now `finalJson` is `[300,"asd","s",1]`

**Edit**: libraries are as following:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler `gson.toJson(hm.values())`? Putting the collection into a list, then converting it to an array... Seems totally unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

Could I ask why do you want to do that? If you retrieve that Json without `key-value` how you will know, for example, that `300` is his `id` and not his `money` property?

You can't difference between your properties and I don't really recommend it.

Anyway, the only way I find to do that, is to "break" your string manually, replacing your properties with blank values, like `json.replace("\"userID\"", "");` and you should do it for every property.